# Output in table form with 10 digit precision

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I am trying to generate tabular output for the following code.  I am trying to solve transcendental equation and I am using `FindRoot` to solve this equation.  `FindRoot` gives me solutions k and b in the program.  But I need a tabular output which shows k and corresponding b value in a table format.  I need a 10 digit precision for my output too.  Can anyone give me some suggestions?  I tried using Table command by it is not helping me.

```
p = 175;
q = 174;
n = 1.444;
m = 1000;
rmin = 100;
rmax = 250;
F1[r_] = D[BesselJ[m, k r], r];
F3[r_] = D[HankelH1[m, k r], r];
F2[r_] = D[BesselJ[m, n k r] + b BesselY[m, n k r], r];
FindRoot[{F1[q]/BesselJ[m, k q] - F2[q]/(
   BesselJ[m, n k q] + b BesselY[m, n k q] ), 
  F2[p]/(BesselJ[m, n k p] + b BesselY[m, n k p] ) - F3[p]/
   HankelH1[m, k p]}, {{k, 511495/100000 + 0 I}, {b, 0 + 10^-25 I}}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Comment: whats `a`?     ...?

Comment: Your input n=1.444 has only 4 significant digits so you can not get a result with 10 digits of precision. That being said, try with n=1444/1000

Comment: @george2079:please read it as F3[p]

Comment: Raj, you should fix your question. If you won't spend the time to fix your question, why should anybody spend the time to answer it?

Comment: the question title implies `FindRoot` is working and you need formatting help. Is that the case (It does not work for me)

Comment: @george2079 Yes findroot is working...but i need some suggestions on generating tabular output...i tried using table command...its not working..

Comment: @CarlWoll..i fixed it ..thank you